# how do i fix broken encoding in my webapp?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

when i submit a form in my web application some characters (f.e. german [umlauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut)) are broken, when they enter my controller. strings like `üäö` endup like `Ã¼Ã¤Ã¶`. how do i fix this problem?

my setup looks like this:

- spring mvc 3.1.2
- maven 3.0.4 or 2.2.1 (tried both)
- tomcat 7.0.x
- eclipse (sts 3.1.0)
- windows 8

based on answers i already found on stackoverflow i have tried following things.

**added those lines to jsp's:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
...
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

**spcified encoding in pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
...

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
<plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
<plugin>
```

**changes the encoding in eclipse to UTF-8.**

while investigating the problem i made following observations.

- when i right-click files in project (resources and java files) and check the specified encoding, it says UTF-8.
- when i output those characters in jsps(f.e. `<p>öäü</p>`) they are displayed correctly in the browser.
- the problem is present in windows and linux.

thx in advance for your answers.

**UPDATE**:

soleved my issue by adding the [CharacterEncodingFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/filter/CharacterEncodingFilter.html) to my web.xml

Comment: If you have set the property above it's not needed to give the encoding for every plugin, cause the plugins have defaults which are the property. Sou you can get rid of encoding for maven-compiler-plugin, maven-resources-plugin etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise yes, you are right. i was desperate, so i added every configuration i found on stackoverlow :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml file and check the encoding setting:

```
<Connector port="8080" ... URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

It appears that Tomcat needs this setting for UTF-8 to work for HTTP request values, such as request parameters in your GET form submissions (possibly POSTs too).

Comment: Did you need to change the value? If you did, then try deleting tomcat work dir, restarting tomcat and trying one more time, just in case...

Comment: i had to add URIEncoding to my connector - it was not there prior. tried deleting the working dir, but not luck again :(

Answer (score 0):

Every time when issues regarding character encoding occurred I fixed them by using the UNICODE representation of the character. Currently I tried only with Korean and German Alphabet.

Comment: that is not practicable, when the string comes from the user like in my case (form submit, you know).