# wrong Encoding during http request parsing

Tags: java, spring, encoding

I try to submit some information from http form by:

`<form method="GET" action="/springhibernate/notes/addComment">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="content" placeholder="type comment here"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="note.id" value=<c:out value="${note.id}"/>/>
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="send comment"/>
    </form>`

Spring framework maps this submit request to contoroller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "notes/addComment", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addComment(@RequestParam("content") String content, @RequestParam("note.id") String parent_id, ModelMap model) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Long note_id = notesService.addComment(content, Long.valueOf(parent_id));
    return "redirect:viewNote/" + parent_id;
}
```

As result I have: ?°?±???????µ in content variable.

Problem occurs with non-latin chars only.

JSP page contains: <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=WINDOWS-1251" language="java" %>

Comment: For which parameter you are getting that garbage value ?

Comment: Character encoding is a nightmare in servlet applications. I suggest you to read this page from the tomcat documentation that explains lots of the quirks related too all java web containers: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding

Comment: Bhavik Ambani, @RequestParam("content") String content = ?°?±???????µ

Comment: i have a similar problem few hours ago. please take a look [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429112/how-do-i-fix-broken-encoding-in-my-webapp

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem few hours ago. please take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13429112/how-do-i-fix-broken-encoding-in-my-webapp). i posted my solution at the end of the question.